# OpenSSL 3.0.2: SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file returns error:03000072:digital envelope routines::decode error

Tags: c, openssl

When upgrading from OpenSSL 1.1.0 to 3.0.2 an error is being logged when using
[SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file.html).

For example, here's pseudo code that shows a series of successful calls where 1.1.0h succeeds but 3.0.2 fails.

OpenSSL 1.1.0h

```
method=TLS_method()
ctx=SSL_CTX_new(method)
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx,"domain.crt")
---> Returns 1
```

OpenSSL 3.0.2

```
fips_libctx=OSSL_LIB_CTX_new()
OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config(fips_libctx,"C:\Program Files\MyServer\openssl.cnf")
OSSL_PROVIDER_load(NULL,"fips")
method=TLS_method()
ctx=SSL_CTX_new_ex(fips_libctx,NULL,method)
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx,"domain.crt")
---> error:03000072:digital envelope routines::decode error
---> error:0A00018F:SSL routines::ee key too small
```

**Question**

Any ideas why SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file would fail for 3.0.2 but work fine in 1.1.0?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with the [suggestion](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/18113) from Matt at OpenSSL.

> You need to also load the base provider. It is designed to be used in
> conjunction with the FIPS provider and does not include any
> cryptographic algorithms (only encoders and decoders). See the fips
> module guide for a discussion about this:
>
> https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/fips_module.html
>
> The FIPS module does not include any decoders itself - which explains
> the "decode error" that you are seeing.

As he noted, I wasn't loading the "base" provider in openssl.cnf, so I added this call

```
OSSL_PROVIDER_load(NULL,"base")
```

and modified the openssl.cnf to include the base provider section
which allowed the decoder to work on the cert file

```
config_diagnostics = 1
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
providers = provider_sect

[provider_sect]
fips = fips_sect
base = base_sect

[base_sect]
activate = 1

[fips_sect]
activate = 1
install-version = 1
conditional-errors = 1
security-checks = 1
module-mac = 3A:EC:2E:53:3F:92:44:F9:50:13:70:6E:FD:38:37:08:8B:F2:68:56:CC:B4:ED:5F:A1:52:1B:93:15:37:0B:8C
```

Also, seeing as the value "activate = 1" is set for both fips and base,
I probably don't need any calls to OSSL_PROVIDER_load() since this takes care of it

```
OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config(fips_libctx,"C:\Program Files\MyServer\openssl.cnf")
```